# How data entered by user in webpage can be used in a bash script as variable?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to Linux & scripting and need some help. I want to know how the data entered by a user on a website can be used in a bash script. For example, a user enters name on the web and that could be used in the bash script as a variable that is written on another VM. I don't want the whole code for the script, just want the idea of how it could be done.

For example, the user types the following information:

Name: **MAX**

Now that will be used in the script like:

**./script.sh MAX**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This looks like you need some kind of backend application to do so

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do a quick read of the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) page for "CGI" (Common Gateway Interface), which is the grandfather of all web server interfaces.  The W3C reference page is [here](https://www.w3.org/CGI/).

Using CGI, there are two modes:  HTTP GET and HTTP POST.  Looking for those references will provide you with examples of the two approaches.

CGI has built-in logic for parsing variable assignments for input provided via web page forms.

The Apache server is just one of many which are designed to serve up data/pages using the model established by CGI.

The book "How Software Works" gives you a detailed look at that web server interaction and data handling for CGI, among others.